# Ruby - Extract value of a particular key from array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes - @profiles which has data as:

```
[{:user_id=>5, :full_name=>"Emily Spot"},{:user_id=>7, :full_name=>"Kevin Walls"}]
```

I want to get full_name of say user_id = 7? I'm doing the following: but it's throwing an error that expression `@profiles.find{|h| h[':user_id'] == current_user.id}` is nil.

```
name = @profiles.find{ |h| h[':user_id'] == current_user.id }[':full_name']
```

if I use `select` instead of `find` then error is - no implicit conversion of String into Integer.

How do I search through the array of hashes?

**UPDATE:**

After @Eric's answer, I restructured my job model & view actions:

```
  def full_names
    profile_arr||= []
    profile_arr = self.applications.pluck(:user_id)
    @profiles = Profile.where(:user_id => profile_arr).select([:user_id, :first_name, :last_name]).map {|e| {user_id: e.user_id, full_name: e.full_name} }
    @full_names = @profiles.each_with_object({}) do |profile, names|
      names[profile[:user_id]] = profile[:full_name]
    end
  end
```

In the view....,

```
p @current_job.full_names[current_user.id]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, it's not very convenient to extract the name of `user_id` 7. You could modify your data structure a bit :

```
@profiles = [{:user_id=>5, :full_name=>"Emily Spot"},
             {:user_id=>7, :full_name=>"Kevin Walls"}]

@full_names = @profiles.each_with_object({}) do |profile, names|
  names[profile[:user_id]] = profile[:full_name]
end

p @full_names
# {5=>"Emily Spot", 7=>"Kevin Walls"}
p @full_names[7]
# "Kevin Walls"
p @full_names[6]
# nil
```

You didn't lose any information but name look-up is now much faster, easier and more robust.

Comment: Eric, this is an out-of-the-box answer....and actually perfectly worked for me as I have moved the full_names now to controller. I've edited into my original question to show how I structured it before and now applied your inputs.

Comment: @Means: Good to know. You probably should put this logic in the model though.

Comment: Can you suggest if @profiles SQL query in my original question -UPDATE part, can be improved/optimized without that long 'select...map' combination?

Comment: @Means after your edit it is obvious, that this logic should go to the model. You should think about setting up proper associations.

Answer (score 7):

`@profiles` is an array of hashes, with symbols as keys, whereas what you use is `String` objects.

So `':user_id'` is a string, and you want symbol: `:user_id`:

```
@profiles.find{ |h| h[:user_id] == current_user.id }
```

> I want to get `full_name` of say `user_id == 7`

```
@profiles.find { |hash| hash[:user_id] == 7 }.fetch(:full_name, nil)
```

Note, I used [Hash#`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) for case, when there is no hash with value `7` at key `:user_id`.

Comment: Oh yes, silly me....that quote was a mistake. Thx. OK so you mean the safe operator will bypass if value of expression is nil ?

Comment: @Means yea, so if `@profiles.find { |hash| hash[:user_id] == 7 }` returns `nil`, without safe navigation calling `name` on it will raise an exception,whereas with safe navigation it will just return `nil`

Comment: @Means `nil&.non_existing_method` => `nil`

Comment: Sorry, Andrey, but the '&.full_name' threw an error : undefined method `full_name' for {:user_id=>5, :full_name=>"Emily Spot"}:Hash. Only when I append [:full_name] to that @profile.find expression, it works. Any idea?

Comment: @Means my bad, I edited the answer, you are 100% correct, you can't run `full_name` on a hash, because it does not implement that method.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting, to create a new hash that can make things simpler

**Eg:**

```
results = {}
profiles = [
  {user_id: 5, full_name: "Emily Spot"},
  {user_id: 7, full_name: "Kevin Walls"}
]

profiles.each do |details|
  results[details[:user_id]] = details[:full_name]
end
```

Now, results will have:

```
{5: "Emily Spot", 7: "Kevin Walls"}
```

So, if you need to get full_name of say user_id = 7, simply do:

```
results[7] # will give "Kevin Walls"
```

Comment: Michael, you didn't really answer the question. You need to give a solution that returns a specific user's full name. Your answer is close, but I'm going to downvote it until you get a chance to edit or delete your answer.